# wait until jQuery animation's callback is done executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, callback

I have a function that needs to call some functions sequentially. First, a fadeOut is called on a DOM node. In a callback, the DOM node is detached. This is function #1. But, after that is done, I need to call function #2.

So:

```
var func1 = function() {
    console.log('func 1 start');
    elt.fadeOut(2000, callback);
    console.log('func 1 end');
};
var func2 = function() {
    console.log('func 2 start');
    console.log('func 2 end');
};
var callback = function() {
    console.log('func 1 callback start');
    elt.detach();
    console.log('func 1 callback end');
};
func1();
func2();
```

The above outputs:

```
func 1 start
func 1 end
func 2 start
func 2 end
func 1 callback start
func 1 callback end
```

I need the callback to finish before `func2()` is called. How do I do it?

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/y2vj8/2/

[EDIT]:

OK, it seems necessary to give you some explanation of why I want `func2()` called after the callback is finished, else I don't foresee getting an answer soon :(.

`func1` fades a div (call it div1) out and then detaches is from the DOM. This is a publicly available function.

`func2` is a user-defined callback to a certain event (a click on some other div, say, div2). It may be undefined, but it may contain absolutely any code.

When div2 is clicked, `func1()` is called, then `func2()` is evaluated, and if it is a function, it is also called.

If the user calls `func1()` manually, `func2()` is never called.

`func1` is unaware of the click event on div2 and therefore cannot check whether `func2` should be called or not.

Comment: Why not chuck `func2()` at the end of the callback?

Comment: Believe me, if I could do it, I wouldn't even post this question.

Comment: you could use a setInterval and check at each time to see if the callback is completed but i don't like this idea really much

Comment: So you want func 1 start, func 1 end, func1 callback start, func1 callback end and then fun2 start func2 end without calling the func2 in the func1 callback?

Comment: Exactly. I want the entire func1, together with the animation's callback, to finish before I go on to calling any other functions (func2 here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something really silly like this ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y2vj8/5/)):

```
var func1 = function(callback) {
    console.log('func 1 start');
    $('#fadeOut').fadeOut(2000, function() { func1_callback(callback) });
    console.log('func 1 end');

};
var func2 = function() {
    console.log('func 2 start');
    console.log('func 2 end');
};
var func1_callback = function(callback) {
    console.log('func 1 callback start');
    $('#fadeOut').detach();
    console.log('func 1 callback end');
    callback.call();
};
func1(func2);
```

Honestly, I'd probably look at restructuring your app. I don't understand why you're doing it the way you're doing it.

Comment: `$('#fadeOut').fadeOut(2000, func1_callback(callback));` doesn't register a callback, it executes func1_callback immediately.

Comment: Seeing how the other answers (for some reason) don't cut it for the asker, this was the idea I was fiddling with. harhar. :D Maybe, even better, is you can just call the original `callback` and the argument `callback` sequentially in the wrapping function. That way, you won't have to modify the original `callback` function as well.

Comment: Yeah you could definitely do that. I did it that way in case the callback had some kind of animation/delay as well, but it doesn't so I don't know why I did it :p

Comment: I have my reasons for doing things the way I'm doing them. Still, your suggestion is probably the cleanest way of achieving what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Since callback is called out of the normal flow (*i mean based on when some other action finishes*), you need to hook the `func2` in that alternate flow..

one way would be to to call `func2` from inside `callback`, and if that is not possible for some reason, you can call it from inside `func1` like this

```
var func1 = function() {
    console.log('func 1 start');
    elt.fadeOut(2000, function(){ callback(); func2(); });
    console.log('func 1 end');
};
```

---

The direct answer to

> I need the callback to finish before func2() is called. How do I do it?

is

You must call `callback` before calling `func2` ..

Answer (score 0):

You could create a wrapped version of the `fadeOut` method that triggers a custom event:

```
var _oldfade = $.fn.fadeOut;
$.fn.fadeOut = function(duration, callback) {  
    var el = $(this);
    return _oldfade.call(this, duration, function() {
        callback();
        el.trigger('fadeOut')
    });
}
```

Which you can register to handle:

```
elt.bind("fadeOut", func2);
```

It's still not clear to me why you can't simply modify the original callback, but this accomplishes the goal of running `func2` only once the first callback has completed.

See a demo here (click on the `div` to initiate the fade):

- http://jsfiddle.net/sKhuT/